# What is the Oracle.sol equivalent of V0.6 in V0.8?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Chainlink V0.8 no longer includes the `Oracle.sol` class that I used in V0.6 to register the chainlink node. It seems `Operator.sol` replaced that in V0.7 (which I never used). However, the only implementation of `ChainlinkRequestInterface` in V0.8 seems to be `OperatorInterface.sol`.

How to deploy the node operator contract using V0.8 properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `Operator.sol` in `v0.7` and `v0.8`. You can use the interface to interact with a `v0.7` edition of `Operator.sol` in `v0.8`

Comment: Operator.sol is nowhere to be found in v0.8/src/contracts, do we use v0.7 .sol code on v0.8? thanks

Comment: Correct. You'd interact with a v0.7 of Operator.sol